# cannot import confluent_kafka in macOS 10.12?

Tags: macos, python-2.7, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I got the following error:

```
_________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_python.py _________________
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/py/tests/test_python.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
tests/test_python.py:9: in <module>
...
    from confluent_kafka import Producer
.tox/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/confluent_kafka/__init__.py:2: in <module>
    from .cimpl import (Consumer,  # noqa
E   ImportError: dlopen(/Users/py/.tox/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/confluent_kafka/cimpl.so, 2): Symbol not found: _syslog$DARWIN_EXTSN
E     Referenced from: /Users/py/.tox/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/confluent_kafka/.dylibs/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
E     Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
E    in /Users/py/.tox/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/confluent_kafka/.dylibs/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
```

So, How to fix this? cannot import confluent_kafka on macOS 10.12?

Thanks

Comment: Python2 is end of life. Have you tried installing in Python3?

Comment: `confluent_kafka/.dylibs/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)` ... Seems like you should upgrade your Mac?